# Как сделать всплывающий блок со скроллингом по вертикали?

Tags: css, html

Второй час пытаюсь придумать решение к CSS/HTML задаче:

По центру страницы, с некоторым отступом сверху, отобразить DIV-блок с плавающей высотой.
В случае, если содержимое блока превышает высоту экрана пользователя - применять невидимый скролл страницы, то бишь дать возможность прокручивать блок по вертикали. Фреймы применять нельзя.

**Обновление**

Сейчас всплывающий блок сделан, но при его прокрутке скроллится родительская страница.

Comment: http://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/BkDie

Может быть, это имели в виду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: Вроде бы подходящее решение, только не найду, как привязать клик к открытию определенного блока. Все примеры приведены, когда внутри кликабельного блока вставлен блок всплывающий.
___

В целом все гуд. Единственное, полоса прокрутки присутствует всегда. Было бы хорошо ее скрыть и скроллить без.